Why does the letter animation work outside a <button> but not inside it?
I'm trying to animate letters so they fly in from random positions using JavaScript. The animation works perfectly when the letters are directly inside the .container class. However, when I move the letters inside a <button> element, the animations no longer work as expected—the letters appear in the center instead of flying in from random positions.
I suspect the issue might be related to how the button affects the layout or positioning of the letters. How can I fix this and keep the letters inside the button without breaking the animation?
Here's my code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Letter Animation</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #282c34;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            gap: 5px;
            font-size: 2rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
        }

        .letter {
            position: relative;
            opacity: 0;
            animation: flyIn 1.5s ease forwards;
        }

        @keyframes flyIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translate(var(--random-x), var(--random-y));
            }
            to {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: translate(0, 0);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="button"> <!-- the problem here when I add the letters inside this button-->
            <span class="letter">L</span>
            <span class="letter">e</span>
            <span class="letter">t</span>
            <span class="letter">'</span>
            <span class="letter">s</span>
            <span class="letter">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="letter">o</span>
            <span class="letter">r</span>
            <span class="letter">g</span>
            <span class="letter">a</span>
            <span class="letter">n</span>
            <span class="letter">i</span>
            <span class="letter">z</span>
            <span class="letter">e</span>
            <span class="letter">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="letter">e</span>
            <span class="letter">v</span>
            <span class="letter">e</span>
            <span class="letter">r</span>
            <span class="letter">y</span>
            <span class="letter">t</span>
            <span class="letter">h</span>
            <span class="letter">i</span>
            <span class="letter">n</span>
            <span class="letter">g</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <script>
        const letters = document.querySelectorAll('.letter');

        function animateLetters() {
            letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
                const randomX = (Math.random() - 0.5) * window.innerWidth; // Random X
                const randomY = (Math.random() - 0.5) * window.innerHeight; // Random Y

                letter.style.setProperty('--random-x', `${randomX}px`);
                letter.style.setProperty('--random-y', `${randomY}px`);

                letter.style.animationDelay = `${index * 0.2}s`;
            });
        }

        animateLetters();
    </script>
</body>
</html>




I added a button into the div with the class "container" and the animation works the same as before. Are you sure there is no Syntax Error in your code?

Like @Lukinator I saw no problem when I added a button element. You need to show us code which demonstrates the problem. And while you are at it, please make it a runnable snippet (use the '<>' in the editor).

I'm new here guys sorry for not giving the specific information, the thing is that problem appears when I put the letters inside the button, while I want the animation  when you remove it so when I put the spans inside the button then the animation different that is the issue

Please provide an example of the expected output. At this point it's unclear what you actually want as there seems to be no issue with the code posted.

here it's not working as I want if you remove the button I mean I edit the post above

We are not mindreaders, we don't know what you want unless you provide an example.

Could you explain exactly what you mean when you say 'keep the letters inside the button'? Do you mean that they are children of the button element (as in your code) BUT that you want them to 'fly in' from outside the button at the beginning and then they stay within the button?

just remove the button! see the animation? this the animation I want. Now put the button back! you can see animation changes because of it and this is the problem and I can't get why is that

Well, you've confined the letters inside the button - and all the positioning is relative - so that's the problem.

so what should I do?

You have put the button as the parent of the spans whereas the parent was .container in the original. However, you have not moved the styling. Give button the same style as .container and it looks OK - ie the letters fly in from outside the button.
